# @Input decorator not working when value changes

Tags: angular

I have a weird problem. I use @Input to pass data from parents to child component. The data will be updated through subscribe, but upon changing the value it doesn't get pass to the child component.

Parent component

`<app-family-tab [pheno]="pheno" [samples]="ids"></app-family-tab>`

```
public ids: string[] = [];
this.subscriptions.push(this.sampleSearch.results.subscribe(s => {
    this.ids = s.samples;
    this.cd.detectChanges();
}));
```

Child component

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectorRef, OnDestroy, Input, Output, EventEmitter, OnInit, AfterViewInit, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-family-tab',
  templateUrl: './family-tab.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./family-tab.component.css']
})
export class FamilyTabComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @Input() pheno: any;
  @Input() samples: string[];
  constructor() { }

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    console.log(this.samples);
  }

}
```

samples doesn't get updated on child component

Comment: can you please try to check changes of samples in ngOnChanges method instead of ngAfterViewInit

Comment: Please try and replicate this in a stackblitz.

Answer (score 0):

`ngAfterViewInit()` is only called once (see the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)). you may want to monitor your `Input` property with `ngOnChanges()` which is run every time an `Input` change.

You could do it like this, with a `SimpleChanges` parameters:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  console.log(changes);
}
```

The `console.log` should return an object with your property name as key and previous and current values:

```
{
  samples: { 
    currentValue: {...}, 
    firstChange: true|false, 
    previousValue: {...} 
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes I know ngAfterViewInit only called once, but the value doesn't change even if I console.log 10seconds after. Shouldn't the value automatically changed everytime parent component change its value even without ngOnChanges?

Answer (score 0):

```
private _samples;
@Input()
set samples(data) {
  console.log(data);
  this._samples = data;
}
```

this way you should get console.log immedietaly after data changed